# Server only updates after forced restart with node express project

Tags: node.js, express

So i've been googling around, and I'm really unsure how to fix this. But its as the title suggests.

I'm new to node and I have my (very basic) node project up and running on my production server. Click a button and it grabs a json file via reddit api, parses and displays. While it works, it doesn't actually refresh the list, its stale. It takes a manual force restart to update the list. It worked fine on my local.

My only dependencies are as follows

```
ejs, express, moment, and request.
```

Is there something I need to add to my node project?

quick paste: http://pastebin.com/qQgP1MT7

Comment: Could you post some code. How do you fetch the JSON file, parse and display that file?

Comment: @saintedlama http://pastebin.com/qQgP1MT7

Comment: The pastebin is not available anymore - You'll get more and better answers if you add your code here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess server is returning `302`

on `app.js` add `app.disable('etag')` before your router

```
var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.disable('etag')

// routes
app.use('/api/', apiRoutes);
```

Comment: Hey dude, thank you for responding. I'll definitely test it out!